# Visual Studio 2012, can not load project file

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am using visual studio 2012. My system was shutdown abnormally and visual studio was running at that time. After then Im facing strange issue, my project file is not loaded and visual studio says, file not loaded. It is also showing me an html file, UpgradeLog.htm. In this file, its showing me this error: HttpServerTest\HttpServerTest.csproj: Error on line 1. Expected '<' but found 'null character'.

Not sure how to fix this, tried following solution by removing .suo file but its not working for me

http://www.howtosolutions.net/2013/02/solving-project-file-error-could-not-find-part-of-the-path-with-visual-studio/

Strange thing is, Its not opening my program.cs file, however its showing correct file size. But when I try to open program.cs file, its opening an empty file.

Any idea?

thank you

Comment: What's the content of your csproj-file?

Comment: have you tried re-importing the project? Also it could be that there is a bad bit of XML in the csproj file, open it up and take a read

Comment: Thank you. csproj-file is not displaying any data, when I tried to run that. However file size is correct, 4KB. Not sure, why its not displaying any thing. Same is the case with program.cs file.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting .suo files in your solution folder. Solution User Option file is a binary file which contains various user information and settings such as location of the breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new solution file and then add the existing project file (or folder)...

Answer (score 0):

if you have any back up of your project, then try to copy content of .csproj file to your current file

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to this with Visual Studio 2013 today.  It turned out we had somehow gotten an invisible character at the beginning of our *.csproj file (we think it got there from a bad merge).

We used https://www.xmlvalidation.com/ to find the invisible character:

```
    1   &#65279;<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Opening the *.csproj file in Notepad++, going to the beginning of the first line, and backspacing, removed the character and allowed Visual Studio to correctly load the project.